# Map data structure implementation

Tags: haskell, functor

What's the problem w this `Functor` instance?

```
data Map k v = Map [(k, v)] deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Functor (Map a) where
  fmap _ (Map []) = Map []
  fmap f (Map xs) = Map xs'
    where xs' = map (\(k, v) -> (f k, v)) xs
```

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: `(\(k, v) -> (k, v))` doesn't do anything. It seems you forgot to use `f` there.

Comment: Well the compiler gives an error. Usually that is a good starting point to debug.

Comment: You are applying f to k instead of v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we compile this, we get the error:

```
<interactive>:6:21: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘b’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b. (a1 -> b) -> Map a a1 -> Map a b
        at <interactive>:5:3
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b. (a1 -> b) -> Map a a1 -> Map a b
        at <interactive>:5:3
      Expected type: Map a b
        Actual type: Map a a1
    • In the expression: Map xs'
      In an equation for ‘fmap’:
          fmap f (Map xs)
            = Map xs'
            where
                xs' = map (\ (k, v) -> (k, v)) xs
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Map a)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs' :: [(a, a1)] (bound at <interactive>:7:11)
        xs :: [(a, a1)] (bound at <interactive>:6:15)
        f :: a1 -> b (bound at <interactive>:6:8)
        fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Map a a1 -> Map a b
          (bound at <interactive>:5:3)
```

The error actually is a good starting point: it says that your `fmap` should have signature:

```
fmap :: forall a1 b. (a1 -> b) -> Map a a1 -> Map a b
```

but apparently your output type is `Map a a1`, so you did not met these contracts. If we further investigate, we see that `map (\(k, v) -> (k, v)) xs` actually does not do much (except repacking the data in a *new* tuple). The output tuple should have type `(a, b)` instead of `(a, a1)` (`a1` being the original type of the *values* in the `Map`).

We thus should apply `f` on the value, like:

```
instance Functor (Map a) where
  fmap _ (Map []) = Map []
  fmap f (Map xs) = Map xs'
    where xs' = map (\(k, v) -> (k, f v)) xs
```

or in a more clean way:

```
instance Functor (Map a) where
  fmap f (Map xs) = Map (fmap (fmap f) xs)
```

Note that you do not need to implement two separate cases here (one for an empty and one for a non-empty list), since a `map` (or `fmap`) on an empty list is an empty list.

Comment: is it possible to apply the function on the key?

Comment: @barnabasmarkus: no, since `Functor f`, expects an `f` with one type parameter, and here that is the value. You can of course redesign it, and define a `Map v k`, such that you can `fmap` on the values, but not the way the `Map` is currently defined.

Comment: thanks a lot! that was my original question, but somehow I have made a mistake when I posted here!